# Using Web Sockets in a Rails 4 application with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket

I'm working in a Rails `4.2.7` application and need to use WebSockets. Unfortunately I can't upgrade to Rails 5 and use Action Cable for this.

The application is using Puma in production, I say this because I found some gems that are meant to be used for Web Sockets but they work just in `Thin` app server but not with `Puma` app server.

Is there any easy solution for this?

Specifically what I need to do is trigger an event to my clients (browsers in this case) every time my model is updated

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :notify_users, if: :some_condition

  def notify_users
    # Trigger a web socket event to my clients here
  end
end
```

I have tried with https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails, and the message gets sent according to the logs, but I'm not receiving it on the browser, and unfortunately it seems that the gems is not maintained anymore.

Is there a solutions that might work for this situation? Thanks

Comment: Is Puma super important? `iodine` provides similar features (multi-threading, multi-processing) as well as Native Websockets (much faster than any Ruby implementation I tested against), static file service etc'... I'm biased, since I'm the author, but I think it's a better fit for websockets (I think it's also faster, but you can test that yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/589) it sounds like the best bet is [tubesock](https://github.com/ngauthier/tubesock)